# Why my AWS S3 bucket redirecting to HTTPS not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have my custom domain (file.example.com) hosted in Namecheap and DNS. Now I have AWS S3 bucket which I am trying to point to my custom domain (file.example.com). What I did is that I have set all the properties and permissions in AWS S3 bucket as well as created Cloudfront distribution to redirect my custom domain to Https. Now I can access every objects using my custom domain URL (file.example.com/sample.pdf), but the HTPPS is not working inspite of creating Cloudfront distribution and generating SSL certificate.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you say not working, what error do you get exactly when you try to access it using HTTPS?

Comment: I have shown the error in my question

Comment: Does the same work with Http?

Comment: Yes the same URL is opening in HTTP.

Comment: I would recommend, please open the chrome developer tool and inspect the requests and their response code. That will lead us in right direction.

Comment: Yes sir I have shared the screenshot. Please see above in my question.

Comment: Is it a SPA app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250702/discussion-between-ankush-jain-and-abhishek-chatterjee).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion over chat, it seems the `CNAME` for your sub-domain `file.example.com` is pointing to the **S3 bucket** URL instead of **CloudFront**.

Because I can not see CloudFront anywhere in the response headers. Can you please update that and then try?

Comment: Thanks sir for your valuable suggestion. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Redirection for HTTP to HTTPS is handled in the Behavior settings for the distribution. In your CloudFront console, open up your distribution to where you took that screenshot. At the top of the page, you'll see a horizontal navbar. Click the `Behavior` entry. You'll likely only have one entry. Click the radio button, and go to `Edit`. The setting you'll be looking for is the `Viewer protocol policy` which needs to be set to `Redirect  HTTP to HTTPS` (see below).

It may take a few minutes after saving the changes for the update to be made to the CloudFront network.

[image]

Comment: Yes I have done that also. But still it is not getting redirected.